# Angular 9 SSR - where to set global['window'] (using domino)?

Tags: angular, angular9

After upgrading to Angular 9, I'm getting error `ReferenceError: window is not defined` when running `yarn serve:ssr`.

In our Angular apps, we use trick with Domino to emulate window for SSR (as in https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter/blob/master/server.ts#L21 ).

So after `ng update` I have added these lines after imports in `server.ts`:

```
const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

// Emulate browser APIs
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const templateA = fs.readFileSync(join(distFolder, indexHtml)).toString();

const win = domino.createWindow(templateA);
win.Object = Object;
win.Math = Math;
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
```

However, it seems that setting `global['window']` is happening either too late or never.

Do you have any idea where to set `global['window']` so the angular components and libraries can access it in SSR?

Comment: DId you find any workround? I have the same problem =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved, thanks to this comment https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1678#issuecomment-627031128

The key is to have line

```
import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
```

**after** the definition of `global['window']`

Beware the autoformatters in your editor, which usually put the import lines on top of the file automatically :)

Answer (score 0):

I put it below the imports and above the app() method

```
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync, readFileSync } from 'fs';
import * as domino from 'domino';
import * as core from 'express-serve-static-core';


const template = join('browser', 'index.html');
const win = domino.createWindow(template);

global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): core.Express {
```

Comment: This doesn't work - still getting `ReferenceError: window is not defined` in `dist/server/main.js`

Comment: Any fix for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I do two tasks to fix it.

first -  in angular.json  set "optimization": false  for server build, its helps find 3d paty module what calls error

second - i move up domino in my server.ts